# How do i display the end date from StartDate in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am using SQL SERVER 2008. I have a table called `Cut-Off` table. This table only shows the `StartDate` of cut-off for every month. So i am creating a temp table that will store `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Month` and `Year`. But i don't know how to get the `EndDate` with `datetime`.

**TABLE**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
StartDate              EndDate     Month   Year
----------------------------------------------------------
2014-12-15 00:00:00     NULL        12      2014
2015-01-26 00:00:00     NULL         1      2015
2015-02-26 00:00:00     NULL         2      2015
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    StartDate              EndDate                   Month   Year
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    2014-12-15 00:00:00     2015-01-25  23:59:99       12     2014
    2015-01-26 00:00:00     2015-02-25  23:59:99       1      2015
    2015-02-26 00:00:00     2015-03-25  23:59:99       2      2015
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How i get the EndDate??

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: hai @shree.pat18. i am using SQL server management studio 2008.

Comment: OK. This would become simpler to do in SQL 2012 with the `LEAD` function. You can replicate this using a self join. Take a look at this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was unable to get 99 seconds in '23:59:99'

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, Month int, Year int)

INSERT #temp values
  ('2014-12-15 00:00:00', NULL, 12, 2014),
  ('2015-01-26 00:00:00', NULL, 1, 2015),
  ('2015-02-26 00:00:00', NULL, 2, 2015)

UPDATE t
SET EndDate = DateAdd(m, DateDiff(m, 0, StartDate), '1900-02-25T23:59:59')
FROM #temp t

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Result:

```
StartDate                EndDate                  Month  Year
2014-12-15 00:00:00.000  2015-01-25 23:59:59.000  12     2014
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000  2015-02-25 23:59:59.000  1      2015
2015-02-26 00:00:00.000  2015-03-25 23:59:59.000  2      2015
```

Edit:

If you want to calculate the EndDate from next StartDate, here is your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE t
SET EndDate = (SELECT top 1 DateAdd(s, -1, StartDate) FROM #temp 
               WHERE t.StartDate < StartDate 
               ORDER BY startdate)
FROM #temp t
```

Result:

```
StartDate                EndDate                  Month  Year
2014-12-15 00:00:00.000  2015-01-25 23:59:59.000  12     2014
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000  2015-02-25 23:59:59.000  1      2015
2015-02-26 00:00:00.000  null                     2      2015
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the cut-off date to be calculated from the Date of the next (LEAD) record.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I thought the same at first, but not possible, the EndDate could not be calculated, since there is no March month StartDate in the testdata

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos made script to handle that as well

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(DATES DATETIME,DATES DATETIME,[MONTH] INT,[YEAR] INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT '2014-12-15 00:00:00',     NULL,       12,      2014
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-01-26 00:00:00',     NULL,       1,      2015
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-02-26 00:00:00',     NULL,       2,      2015
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY STARTDATE)RNO, STARTDATE
    FROM #TEMP
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT C1.STARTDATE,
    ISNULL(DATEADD(S,-1,C2.STARTDATE),DATEADD(S,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,C1.STARTDATE))) ENDDATE 
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1
)
UPDATE #TEMP
SET EndDate = CTE2.ENDDATE
FROM #TEMP T1
JOIN CTE2 ON T1.STARTDATE=CTE2.STARTDATE
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with OUTER APPLY

```
select
    c.StartDate
    DATEADD(SECOND,-1,e.StartDate) EndDate
    DATEPART(MONTH,StartDate) [Month],   
    DATEPART(YEAR,StartDate) [Year]
from [Cut-Off] c
outer apply (
    select TOP 1
        e.StartDate
    from [Cut-Off] e
    where
        e.StartDate > c.StartDate
    order by
        e.StartDate
) e
```